# ASP.NET Identity, Losing Ability to Login until Application Pool Recycles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

Here's my problem.  I'm using ASP.NET Identity in a ASP.NET Web Form project (I know, old technology).  The login works fine most of the time, but one of my end users says he loses that ability once in a while.  We kind of narrowed it down to it being browser/device specific.  Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?  I've done as much research as I can but can't seem to pinpoint the problem.  I've tried to replicate the problem, but I'm unable to.  The login always works for me.  I do know that recycling the application pool always fixes the problem.